# How to proceed for performance testing on an application which is not in production?

Tags: performance, loadrunner

How to proceed with performing performance testing for an application that is not in production.

Comment: Please clarify.  The mechanical aspects of producing a perforamance test are the same for a preprod application as one in production (save the environment items and scheduling to test in non-intrusive ways to existing users if testing in production)

Comment: Hi James.I just want to know if one application is not in production what should be our approach to go ahead with performing performance testing.what are details we should ask to dev team or clinet so that we can start the planning of performance testing.

Comment: See performance requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If the environment of the application under test is the same as it will be in production - the approach should not be different.

If the environment of the application under test is different, i.e. has less servers, the servers has less memory, etc. - in the absolute majority of cases you will not be able to calculate and predict the performance on more powerful hardware as there are too many factors to consider. You can inform the client about it right away.

However there are still some types of testing you can perform, i.e.:

- You could run an [integration test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) to check whether your application is configured for high load
- You could run a [scalability test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability_testing) to check whether and how does your application scale
- You could run a [soak test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing) to check for possible memory leaks
- You could use [profiling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) to check bottlenecks in terms of code quality
- You could identify [slow DB queries](https://stackify.com/performance-tuning-in-sql-server-find-slow-queries/) and look for a way to optimise them
- etc.

More information: [Performance Testing in a Scaled Down Environment. Part Two: 5 Things You Can Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-scaled-down-environment-part-two-five-things-you-can-test)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant how to judge on how much volume to test if application is not already in production, the answer is simple, you have to predict. The prediction can be based on survey, reports from your business analysts.

If none of the above are available. Just test how much your application can withstand in a test environment of similar configuration as production. This will give you an idea of when you need to start worrying while the application is live.